# Bundle commands not working due to proxy settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, proxy, bundler

I have a rails application that I set to use a proxy so that I could update gems in my school's LAN.

However now that I'm not using the school's network, when I do

```
 bundle install
```

I get this error

```
 Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler
 troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
 /home/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/generic.rb:214:in `initialize': the scheme http does not accept registry part: cavs@students:cavsuon@proxy.uonbi.ac.ke:80 (or bad hostname?) (URI::InvalidURIError)
```

When I also do

```
 gem update bundler
```

or

```
 gem update --system
```

I get this error

```
 ERROR:  While executing gem ... (URI::InvalidURIError)
the scheme https does not accept registry part: cavs@students:cavsuon@proxy.uonbi.ac.ke:80 (or bad hostname?
```

I cannot recall how I set up my app to use proxy but even when I did it has never worked so I thought that it was never using a proxy in the first place.

How can I unset this proxy configuration and set it again if I'm on my school's network

Upon doing

```
 echo $http_proxy
```

as suggested, I get

```
 http://cavs@students:cavsuon@proxy.uonbi.ac.ke:80
```

How do I unset $http_proxy

Answer (score 0):

By default it may be picking up the http_proxy environment variable.

Try running

```
echo $http_proxy
```

on the command line to see what it gives back to you. You can set that value using

```
export http_proxy=http://user:password@host:port
```

If that doesn't work, also see what HTTP_PROXY is set to.

You can unset a variable temporarily by using `unset http_proxy`. If it is something you need to change more permanently (i.e. it is there every time you open a terminal) you will need to check the various hidden files in your home directory (i.e. .profile or .bashrc) to find and remove it.

Comment: Hi Chris, try    unset http_proxy

Comment: Tried that....and when I do echo $http_proxy I don't get anything but still when I run bundle update I get the same problem

Comment: Do the same with HTTP_PROXY all caps and see if anything is there

Comment: Check your .gemrc file to see if you have a proxy configured there

Comment: I don't have that file in my app but I did  locate gemrc  which returned /opt/vagrant/embedded/etc/gemrc ... on opening this file it only contains  gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc --no-user-install

Comment: only other thing I can suggest here is searching your local config for anything that may be setting that value... i.e. grep -r "proxy.uonbi.ac.ke" ~

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem which turned out to be the problem in [Ruby itself](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems.org/issues/391):

> The problem is related to the uri component of Ruby itself, which
>   tries to match the userinfo part of the URI

So, in your case, according to [this](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems.org/issues/391) regexp doesn't accept **@** character and you should modify your ***/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/uri/common.rb***:

```
   -ret[:USERINFO] = userinfo = "(?:[#{unreserved};:&=+$,]|#{escaped})*"
   +ret[:USERINFO] = userinfo = "(?:[#{unreserved};:&=+$,@]|#{escaped})*"
```

Answer (score 0):

run `export http_proxy=http://x.x.x.x:8080`  on the command line and then check if that has changed using `echo $http_proxy`.  This worked for me on 12/18/2018